# How to add libcurl in clion

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, libcurl, clion

After install 
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

i trying to add curl in cmake of clion,but i can't understand how make this.
this my standart cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(untitled3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(untitled3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be able to help you.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(untitled3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lcurl")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(untitled3 curl)
```